# Pass Data from Fragment to another fragment, same activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

im trying to send data from fragment 1, to fragment 2.

Im getting a `NullPointerException`, and i dont quite know why..

I have searched on google and found a lot of articles about, what im trying to do, but i just cant figure out how the general way is done, and if its even possible=(

sorry for using bad english, and im a beginner so...

Code used in Fragment 1

```
  public interface DataMessage {
        public void send(String message);


   }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
try {SM = (DataMessage)activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
throw new ClassCastException("Implement message interface");
}
```

Code Used in Fragment 2

```
  public void getData(String message){
        edt.setText(message);
        Log.i("Disp", "ListHistoryFragment " + message);
    }
```

Code used in Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, ListHistoryFragment.DataMessage
        ...




  @Override
    public void send(String message) {
        //DisplayFragment DispFrag = (DisplayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmenttest);
        DisplayFragment DispFrag = new DisplayFragment();

        FragmentTransaction Transfer = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DispFrag.getData(message);
        Transfer.replace(R.id.container, DispFrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        Log.i("Acitivyt", "ListHistoryFragment " + message);


    }
```

Log Cat:

```
 1-22 11:39:01.580  22399-22399/rampanere.packed.package.nl E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.rampa.pack.nl.SQL.DisplayFragment.getData(DisplayFragment.java:152)
            at android.rampa.pack.nl.MyActivity.send(MyActivity.java:265)
            at android.rampa.pack.nl.SQL.ListHistoryFragment$1.onItemClick(ListHistoryFragment.java:73)
```

EDIT:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    SM.send(message);
                }
```

Comment: Use Share Prefrences for Sharing DAta between activities and Fragments

Comment: how do you call `send` method in your fragment? copy you code please.

Answer (score 0):

To share data between fragments and activities you should keep an instance of the data you are planning to share in your activity. SharedPreferences are intended to other purposes, for example, storing data that you will need whenever your application starts.

Inside your activity declare a protected/public String called message for example.

```
public class MyActivity extends .... {

    public String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
}
```

Inside your first fragment, whenever you want to save your String use.

```
((NAMEOFYOURACTIVITY) getActivity()).message = "THE STRING YOU WANT TO SHARE";
```

Inside your second fragment, to retrieve your message use:

```
((NAMEOFYOURACTiIVTY) getActivity()).message;
```

For example:

```
Log.i("The string in","my activity is: "+((NAMEOFYOURACTiIVTY) getActivity()).message);
```

Comment: getActivity is used in fragments, not activities right?

Comment: yes, getActivity() will return an instance of the Activity that loaded the fragment. I just edited my answer =)

Comment: SO, a method called message(), should be declared in main activity,  for me to share it?

The string i want to share though, is created in Fragment 1.

Comment: Check my newly edited answer. Not a method, just a field of your Activity class that is visible for all the fragments you load there.

Comment: But how do i pass the string or value made in Fragment 1 to activity? How do i pass it onto the `public String message;`??

Comment: Just use `((MyActivity) getActivity()).message = your_message;` inside your fragment 1, whenever your message is ready. That will make your message public String stores your message from fragment 1.

Comment: So do i need any of the code i used before? or do i just need to apply these : ` public String message;`, `((NAMEOFYOURACTiIVTY) getActivity()).message;` `((NAMEOFYOURACTiIVTY) getActivity()).message = message;` Would this be enough for me to pass it on to my other fragment? Or do i still need to use an interface? new methods or something like that?

Comment: That will handle your problem. Give it a shot, and if you have more doubts, please let me know.